# Applescript: forwarding subject of mail as mobile short message (SMS) via Skype

Tags: applescript

In apple mail (Mail.app), I defined a rule that calls an applescript when receiving an email. The script should send the subject of the mail as an SMS message via Skype (it should also send the name of the sender). I've got already a script working that sends some hardcoded text as SMS, but I don't know how to pass the subject and senders name from mail into that SMS. Here's my script:

```
# Code adapted from:
# http://photolifetoys.blogspot.de/2011/12/applescript-control-over-skype-call.html

# VARIABLES
set callToAnumber to "+01234567890"
set SMSmessageBody to " has sent a mail."
set SenderOfMail to "TheSenderOfTheEmail"
set MailSubject to "TheSubjectOfTheMail" 


# BODY
set smstext to "SenderOfMail" & SMSmessageBody as Unicode text
tell application "Skype"
    set message to send command "CREATE SMS OUTGOING " & callToAnumber script name "SMS"
    set smsid to item 2 of every word of message
    send command "SET SMS " & smsid & " BODY " & smstext script name "SMS"
    set result to send command "ALTER SMS " & smsid & " SEND" script name "SMS"
    #display dialog "SMS send! Text: " & smstext
end tell
```

Comment: which mail client are you using?  Apple's Mail.app or something else?

Comment: I am using Mail.app

Comment: Its difficult to grasp what you're looking for in this question without a question. Are you looking for how to retrieve the sender and subject from the mail app and store it as a variable? Are you looking for the code to be written for you to do what you explain is supposed to happen? So far you've grabbed two blocks from a 5-6 year old script and said it doesn't do what you want, and you don't know how to make it do extra stuff.Getting a 5-6 year old script rewritten for your specific needs may prove difficult. A little clarification on exactly what you'd like help on may be beneficial.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: I did not know how to grab the subject and then pass it to the SMS-part of the code … but now I found out it is very easy to do and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Now I've got the answer. Here's the code:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages these_messages for rule this_rule
        tell application "Mail"
            set the message_count to the count of these_messages
            repeat with i from 1 to the message_count
                set this_message to item i of these_messages

                -- GET THE SENDER OF THIS MESSAGE
                set this_sender to the sender of this_message
                -- GET SUBJECT OF MESSAGE
                try
                    set this_subject to (subject of this_message) as Unicode text
                    if this_subject is "" then error
                on error
                    set this_subject to "NO SUBJECT"
                end try
                -- GET CONTENT OF MESSAGE
                try
                    set this_content to (every character of content of this_message) as Unicode text
                    if this_content is in {"", "?"} then error
                on error error_message
                    set this_content to "NO CONTENT"
                end try
            end repeat
        end tell
        set callToAnumber to "+0123456789"

        # BODY
        set smstext to this_subject as Unicode text
        tell application "Skype"
            set message to send command "CREATE SMS OUTGOING " & callToAnumber script name "SMS"
            set smsid to item 2 of every word of message
            send command "SET SMS " & smsid & " BODY " & smstext script name "SMS"
            set result to send command "ALTER SMS " & smsid & " SEND" script name "SMS"
            #display dialog "SMS send! Text: " & smstext
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```